# react-query will not refetch data for cached item after `setQueriesData` is called

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm building a search page with the following behavior:

1. when the page is loaded, execute a query with default search params
2. when the user updates the search params, execute a query with the new params
3. when the user `clears` the search, clear any data but *do not* re-fetch the search until they have entered new params
4. when the user `resets` the search, execute a query with the default search params.

To handle case `3`, I am manually setting the data of the query, because I can't find a method that will allow me to clear the data *without* re-fetching.  This is causing a bug; if the user updates the search params, then clears the search, then uses the previous search params again, the query does not re-fetch, and the manually set "cleared" data persists.

What pattern/method should I be using to force the refetch, even if the query key already exists in the cache?  I have tried using `invalidateQueries` in my `clear` call, but that causes the query to re-fetch, which is not the desired behavior.

```js
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const [params, setParams] = useState(defaultParams);
const {data, isLoading, isFetching} = useQuery({
  querykey: ['search', params],
  queryFn: () => fetch(...),
});

const clearSearch = () => {
  queryClient.setQueriesData({queryKey: ['search'], exact: false}, []});
}

const resetSearch = () => setParams(defaultParams);

const submitSearch = (nextParams) => {
  // if this is called with params = A, and then clearSearch is called,
  // and this is called again with params = A, the query does not re-fetch
  setParams(nextParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with a colleague, I ended up putting a `cacheBuster` parameter into my payload, which I assigned to `Date.now() | null`;

```js
const defaultParams = {foo: 'bar', cacheBuster: null};

const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const [params, setParams] = useState(defaultParams);
const {data, isLoading, isFetching} = useQuery({
  querykey: ['search', params],
  queryFn: () => fetch(...),
});

const clearSearch = () => {
  queryClient.setQueriesData({queryKey: ['search'], exact: false}, []});
  setParams(defaultParams);
}

const resetSearch = () => setParams({...defaultParams, cacheBuster: Date.now()});

const submitSearch = (nextParams) => {
  // Date.now() ensures the params are always different, so the query automatically re-runs.
  setParams({...nextParams, cacheBuster: Date.now());
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my answare i've misunderstood the question.
Anyway have you look for the prop **cacheTime**. 
As wrote in the docs 

The time in milliseconds that unused/inactive cache data remains in memory. When a query's cache becomes unused or inactive, that cache data will be garbage collected after this duration. When different cache times are specified, the longest one will be used.

So if you set it at 0 , every time you make a new request the old one it will be garbage collected.  [reference](https://medium.com/doctolib/react-query-cachetime-vs-staletime-ec74defc483e)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `useEffect` hook to refetch everytime the **params** changes

```
useEffect(() => {
// refetch
}, [params])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your result by using the the **enabled** property in useQuery Hook.
By checking if the param state is not a valid string, you can enable or disable on runtime the useQuery.

As example:

```
export default function Dummy() {
  const [params, setParams] = React.useState('');
  useQuery({
     queryKey: ['search', params],
     enabled: Boolean(params),
     queryFn: () => console.log(params, 'print'),
  });

   return (
     <div className={styles.container}>
       <input
         type="text"
         value={params}
         onChange={(e) => setParams(e.target.value)}
       />
    </div>
  );
 }
```

Comment: According to the documentation, this won't solve my problem:
"The query will automatically update when this key changes (as long as enabled is not set to false)".  Since my queryKey is already in the cache, won't the same behavior I outlined above occur?